# how to fetch last 30 minutes records from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

```
I am using following query to fetch all last 30 minutes records using elastic search, but I'm getting parsable error on line "now-30m".



    Query: 
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "appName": "magnus-alerting-system"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "countryCode": "US2"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "eventCode": 201
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "extractName": "LaborDemand"
          }
        },{
          "range": {
            "eventPostTimestamp": {
              **"gte": "now()-30m"**
            }
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Error on Postman while executing service:
 "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "number_format_exception",
                "reason": "For input string: \"now()-30m\""
            }
        ]

PLease let me know how to correct it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because now()-30m in elasticsearch is wrong since the correct format is just "now".
[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math)

Hence the correct query is the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "appName": "magnus-alerting-system"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "countryCode": "US2"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "eventCode": 201
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "extractName": "LaborDemand"
          }
        },{
          "range": {
          "eventPostTimestamp": {
          "gte": "now-30m"
            }
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for using [data math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) in [range query for date field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) would be as below:

```
{
  "range": {
    "eventPostTimestamp": {
      "gte": "now-30m"
    }
  }
}
```